# Update error if data does not exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I managed to create my own "save, update, delete" program with SQL after watching a video.

I have an issue, if I click "update" without having the "IndexNumber" in the database, nothing will happen.

Can anybody advise me on how to improve my "update" button? Perhaps if the data does not exist, the program can prompt the user with a message box instead of doing nothing. Like "IndexNumber does not exist therefore unable to update"

My update code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + 
    "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE GlennTeoStudents SET IndexNumber = '" + 
    numIN.Value + "',Name = '" + txtName.Text + "',Age ='" + txtAge.Text + 
    "',HandPhoneNumber = '" + txtHP.Text + "',GPA = '" + numGPA.Value + 
    "' WHERE (IndexNumber='" + numIN.Value + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: your update is working fine..bcos the update function is for updating a row exist in the database. So if the indexnumber in ur condition doesnot exist in database it wont update any row :)

Comment: I suggest you to do not use that type of `sqlcommand` because of SQL injection, use a Stored procedure for `UPDATE` in your DB, and use `parameters` in your `sqlcommand` ;).

Comment: Kindly don't use User input values directly into your query. This will make your application prone to Sql Injection. Instead, use SqlCommand.Parameters. Visit [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for details

Comment: Sachu, it is indeed working fine! But I would like a messagebox to appear instead of it doing nothing so that the user know what went wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 try
{
.....
 con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select count(*) from GlennTeoStudents
                         WHERE (IndexNumber='" + numIN.Value + "')", con);

    int count1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (count1 != 0)
      {
    do your update
    }
    else
    {
     give your message box
    }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Sachu! How are you? Same question as Manoj,  
if(numIn.value "Not equal zero") then update? I have a IndexNumber of value of Zero and If numIN "6" does not exist won't it update too? As it it not equal to zero? –

Comment: @MrTeo im doing good..here we are checking whether there is any row exist in database with indexnumber as value in numIn. If so it will return a value > 0 in count1 else it will return 0 as no row found so u can give a message else it will update

Comment: Ah, I get it but I have an issue. There is an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" The error is at  "cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: @MrTeo oh sorry my bad memory do this `int count1  =(int)command.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Why count1 but not count? Is it reserved or something?

Comment: BTW, (int)command.ExecuteSclar(); had an error too but I changed it to "int count1 = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();" command to cmd

Comment: @MrTeo in my eg it cmd is named as command :) so now its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78007/discussion-between-sachu-and-mrteo).

Comment: Oh, I get it. Now I have error if I use "  int count1 (int)command.ExecuteScalar();"    Error The name 'command' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Thanks alot Sachu, you're helpful as always!

Comment: **Do not** do it this way, instead use Parameters - This is open to SQL Injection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of rows affected (int).
You could check on the return value:

```
SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(asd)
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
con.Open();
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
if (!(rowsAffected > 0))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(<Your Message>);
}
```

Then just catch the exception wherever you call the method and display your messagebox with

```
MessageBox.Show(<Your Message>)
```